# PHP: mongoDB - iterative processing

Tags: php, mongodb

What's best practise for running line by line, no sorting/ordering/grouping.

I am going to read each line, update this line, and go on with the next line etc.

It's not possible to update directly without reading before. Is there a really efficient way of going through the collection "document by document"?

The number of documents is around 150Mio and I hope there is a fast feature for processing this task.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are making the exact same update on every document, you will have to run this line by line. Of course, you can use multiple threads/processes to update all the documents. Just make sure that no document is updated twice in that case.

Comment: i.e. there is no more performant alternative to collection.find() + .update() for each document - except with threads/processes. With a selection on a non-indexed field, i could deal with parallel processes, but i am not sure if it's really faster then one thread. the process on each document is not "expensive" for cpu, but it's not the same work with each document... not as cool as nosql should be :/